# how to install rpmrebuild-2.11-3.el7.noarch.rpm on ubuntu system

Tags: rpm

I tried to install rpmrebuild using the below command :

`rpm -ivh rpmrebuild-2.11-3.el7.noarch.rpm`.

But fails with the below errors:
error:

```
Failed dependencies:
        /bin/bash is needed by rpmrebuild-2.11-3.el7.noarch
        /bin/sh is needed by rpmrebuild-2.11-3.el7.noarch
        rpm-build is needed by rpmrebuild-2.11-3.el7.noarch
        textutils is needed by rpmrebuild-2.11-3.el7.noarch
```

Comment: wow; you are installing rpms on an ubuntu? I think that's asking for trouble... ubuntu is debian based...

Answer (score 1):

Download the tar.gz, then expand and invoke make to install under /usr/lib/rpmrebuild.

```
mkdir /tmp/rpmrebuild &&\
cp rpmrebuild-2.14.tar.gz /tmp/rpmrebuild/ &&\
cd /tmp/rpmrebuild/ &&\
tar xvfz rpmrebuild-2.14.tar.gz &&\
sudo make &&\
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0):

besides the question whether it is a good idea to install rpms on a debian-based os (like ubuntu); rpm does not manage dependencies; in the same way `dpkg` won't do that for you either. So you have two options:

1. search online and make sure you download the rpms that are needed (in this case bash*.rpm, rpm-build*.rpm, coreutils*.rpm and maybe others; then when installing you need to specify them all at once on the command line: `rpm -ivh rpmrebuild-2.11-3.el7.noarch.rpm bash*.rpm rpm-build*.rpm
   coreutils*.rpm`
2. use a package manager; like `zypper` or `yum` which uses *repositories* where it looks for the required packages for you and installs them. Again; no idea how that's going to work out on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

```
rpm -ivh --nodeps rpmrebuild-2.11-3.el7.noarch.rpm
```

Assuming you already have the dependecies natively installed.

Developing linux orientated applications under Ubuntu I've come across some backwards difficulties creating functional rpm 4.4 packages. **rpmrebuild** helps solving that issue. I do not use rpm tools to maintain my system - only for interacting with the packages/sources themselves ;)

Answer (score -1):

You might try the rpm option `--nodeps`; that should cause rpm to ignore missing dependencies.  You are then on the hook for installing them yourself.  /bin/bash and /bin/sh should already be in place (although on Ubuntu /bin/sh pointing to dash might cause problems).  If you've already got rpm installed then I think you can ignore rpm-build:

```
$ rpm-build
No command 'rpm-build' found, did you mean:
 Command 'rpmbuild' from package 'rpm' (universe)
rpm-build: command not found
```

No guess what textutils covers.  You might try grabbing that package from a centos repo, and unpacking it.  (Google how to do it but has something to do with cpio and a pipe.)  I suspect that those files might be part of your Ubnuntu install already.

Good luck but proceed with extreme caution.  As others have noted mixing rpms into an otherwise Ubuntu system may cause problems.